# Using nested statements in JS?

Tags: javascript, nested

I'm working my way through a video series about JavaScript (I've been put in charge of our company website, but have no real web design training). Anyways, working my through these videos, and I'm noticing that none of my programs that have nested statements are working. Is anyone able to see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Using Nested "for" Loops</title>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

for (var jsNotjava=0; jsNotjava<8; jsNotjava++) {
    document.write("JavaScript is not Java!<br>");
         for (var jsNotjava2=1; jsNotJava2<2; jsNotjava2++) {
        document.write("Are you with me so far?<br>");
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What is the expected result?

Comment: The expected result is that it should write out the first statement for a set number of times, then write out the second statement underneath the first one for a set number of times. This isn't a real-world application.

Answer (score 2):

Right now you're writing in the head of the document. Write in the body. You also have a case problem (in the inner loop, `jsNotJava2` != `jsNotjava2`) :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Using Nested "for" Loops</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

for (var jsNotjava=0; jsNotjava<8; jsNotjava++) {
    document.write("JavaScript is not Java!<br>");
    for (var jsNotjava2=1; jsNotjava2<2; jsNotjava2++) {
        document.write("Are you with me so far?<br>");
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But you should try to go as fast as possible to the lessons not involving `document.write`, it's terrible practice most of the times.